# PowerShell - Error in path while Set-FsrmQuota

Tags: powershell, fileserver

I'm trying to make a script that changes the quota of a specific directory on a remote server. For that I'm using the following code (`$Quota` and `$chosen_username` enter as parameters):

```
$prefix_path = "C:\Shares\Users\";
$path = $prefix_path + $chosen_username;

if($Quota){
    invoke-command -computername $servername {Set-FsrmQuota -path $path -Size $Quota+"GB"}
}

if((invoke-command -computername $servername {Get-FsrmQuota -path $path} | select @{n='QuotaSize'; e={$_.Size / 1gb -as [int]}}).QuotaSize -eq $Quota){
    return "Success."
} else {
    return "Failed."
}
```

And it is giving me this error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-FsrmQuota], ParameterBindingValidationException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Set-FsrmQuota
       + PSComputerName        : ServerName
```

I've done debug and the value of `$path` is correct.

Comment: typo error here : `$path = $prefixo_path+$chosen_username`  ($prefix **o** _path) ?

Comment: In this case, yes, because I'm translating to english, sorry. But in the code it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `invoke-command` on a remote computer, the local variables are unknown for the remote host, so you have to use either:

- the **using** prefix for PS >= 3

  ```
  invoke-command -computername $servername {Set-FsrmQuota -path $using:path -Size $using:Quota+"GB"}
  ```
- the **argumentlist** parameter for PS < 3

  ```
  invoke-command -computername $servername {Set-FsrmQuota -path $args[0] -Size $args[1]+"GB"} -argumentlist $path,$quota
  ```